# Make a library reference another library

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I need to create a static library which will use winsocks.
As you already know in order to use winsocks you need to reference the ws2_32.lib in your project, anyway from visual studio I can't find the "link" tab in which I would usually do that.
If I open another project, a project who is not a library (say a win32 console application) this tab is present...anyway seem strange to me that I can't build a .lib file which, in turn, includes another...I don't think to be the first one who needs to use sockets in a library..or not?

Comment: do you have any source files in your project? You won't have a linker tab if you don't have any C or C++ files.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then, it's certainly possible to build a .lib file which links to other .lib files. What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: ...an old one, the vc++ 6.0, unfortunately for external causes I need to use this one

Comment: ah I don't have a copy of that version (and haven't ever used it); it really should be possible though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved compiling by command line...

```
cl myLib.c /link ws2_32.dll
```